# How to use move and scale UIImagePickerController in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

I am new to iPhone development. I am working with image picker controller in which I want to move and scale the image that picked from the photo library, so I enabled the `allowsediting =  yes`.

And my picker did finish method:

```
 - (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    // Access the uncropped image from info dictionary

    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    self.imgForDisplay.image=[self scaleAndRotateImage:image];
    self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;


    ImageDetailsViewController *imageDetailsVC = [[ImageDetailsViewController alloc] init];
    imageDetailsVC.imagedisplay.image = self.imgForDisplay.image;
    [picker pushViewController:imageDetailsVC animated:YES];



//[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

and I push another view controller where I want to show the Image picked.

Here I have two problems:

1) When I select the image, its navigating to another view without "move and scaling" screen but the image is now displayed in the ImageDetailsViewController when it navigates.

2) When I again navigate back and pick another image, now it shows the "move and scaling" screen. When I click the choose button, it is simply showing a white screen with out navigation bar.

Is there any way to set the action for the choose button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too face the same problem i solved it by using the by using the code, go through this it will be usefull.

```
 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker  
    didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info { 
        self.lastChosenMediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType]; 
        if ([lastChosenMediaType isEqual:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) { 
            UIImage *chosenImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]; 
            UIImage *shrunkenImage = shrinkImage(chosenImage, imageFrame.size); 
            self.image = shrunkenImage; 
        } else if ([lastChosenMediaType isEqual:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie]) { 
            self.movieURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]; 
        } 

        ImageSelectionView *imageSelectionVC = [[ImageSelectionView alloc] init];
        imageSelectionVC.theImage = image;
        [picker pushViewController:imageSelectionVC animated:YES];
        imageSelectionVC.dismissDelegate =self;


       // [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
    }
```

'

```
-(void)updateDisplay { 
    if ([lastChosenMediaType isEqual:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) { 
        imageView.image = image; 
        imageView.hidden = NO; 
        moviePlayerController.view.hidden = YES; 
    } else if ([lastChosenMediaType isEqual:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie]) { 
        [self.moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview]; 
        self.moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] 
                                       initWithContentURL:movieURL] ; 
        moviePlayerController.view.frame = imageFrame; 
        moviePlayerController.view.clipsToBounds = YES; 
        [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view]; 
        imageView.hidden = YES; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: where does the method, shrinkImage come from?  From this line:     UIImage *shrunkenImage = shrinkImage(chosenImage, imageFrame.size);

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be better off presenting your picker modal like this:

```
 if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]){
    UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

Then have your image displayed in the view of the viewcontoller that presented it.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)Btn_AddImage:(id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *Image_Picker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    Image_Picker.delegate=self;
    Image_Picker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentViewController:Image_Picker animated:YES completion:Nil];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSData  *Data=UIImageJPEGRepresentation([info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"], 1);
    UIImage *Cust_Image=[[UIImage alloc]initWithData:Data];
    Profile_Image.image=Cust_Image;
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
}
```